# How do I rename a key in an NSDictionary inside an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `key/value` pair in an `NSDictionary` inside an `NSArray` like

```
foo=bar
```

I need to rename foo in each `NSDictionary` inside the `NSArray` so that they all come out as:

```
jongel=bar
```

I have read some documentation how to extract the keys using the `allKeys` method but I cannot find anything about renaming a key in an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: It is impossible to rename the key, you have to remove object from dictionary, and than add it with new key.

Comment: A dictionary key must implement `Hashable` because the hash of the key is integral to how a dictionary works.  If you change the key, you change the `hashValue` of the key.  So you can't just rename it in-place, you have to remove it and then insert a new key/value pair with the new key and old value.

Answer (score 3):

It's more of a replace than a rename.  Here's a solution that handles the mutability issue and returns a dictionary like the original...

```
- (NSDictionary *)changeKey:(NSString *)key toKey:(NSString *)newKey inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)d {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [d mutableCopy];
    result[newKey] = d[key];
    [result removeObjectForKey:key];
    return result;
}

// elsewhere, call it...
NSDictionary *d = @{ /* your original immutable dictionary */ };
d = [self changeKey:@"foo" toKey:@"jongel" inDictionary:d];
```

This is a candidate for a dictionary extension if you use it a lot.

If it's in an immutable array, **that must be mutable, too**...

```
NSArray *myArray = ...
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [myArray mutableCopy];

NSDictionary *d = myArray[someIndex];
myMutableArray[someIndex] = [self changeKey:@"foo" toKey:@"jongel" inDictionary:d];
myArray = myMutableArray;
```

Comment: "an immutable array, that must be mutable, too", what is that? Why would you do that?

Comment: @iCaramba, we have an array that contains a dictionary that must be replaced.  This means we must mutate that array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need an *NS**Mutable**Dictionary* to do this.

If `oldKey` and `newKey` are known then there are three steps:

```
NSString *oldKey = @"foo";
NSString *newKey = @"jongel";

// get the value
id value = dictionary[oldKey];
// remove the old key
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:oldKey];
// set the new key
dictionary[newKey] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename a key. But you can set a new key.

If you have a mutable dictionary then you can do...

```
dictionary[@"jongel"] = dictionary[@"foo"];
dictionary[@"foo"] = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change anything in an `NSDictionary`, since it is read only.

You Only do that changes in `NSMutableDictionary` with the new key names.

You can get a mutable dictionary of a immutable by calling `mutableCopy` on it.

using

```
- (void)exchangeKey:(NSString *)foo withKey:(NSString *)jongel inMutableDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)aDict
{
//do your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying of an NSDictionary is not possible. 
You can try this way

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int j=0; j<yourArray.count; j++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[yourArray objectAtIndex:j]];

        [dict setObject: [dict objectForKey: @"oldKey"] forKey: @"newKey"];
        [dict removeObjectForKey: @"oldKey"];

        [tempArray addObject:dict];
    }
yourArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:(NSArray *)tempArray];
```